# Magento doubled base url in CSS paths

Tags: css, magento, path

I'm migrating to other server, and in the new server I got this error, the path to all css files are wrong, the js paths are fine, everything else is fine.

Path magento return through getCssJsHtml():
/var/www/domain.com/public/http://domain.com/public/skin/frontend/fortis/default/css/style.css

The path that getSkinUrl() function returns is correct.

Changed the base_url (secure and unsecure) to the new one.
merge_files are 0
cleaned the cache (rm -rf * in var/).
Tried to change ownership of media and var folders to www-data, didn't work as well.

I'm using Fortis theme.
I have GTSpeed extension installed, if I disable it, the head tag shows empty.
 
If I enable css and js compression in GTSpeed I get a 400 Bad request error. 
The admin section always works fine, only thing I noticed is if I change the Link Base Url in Configuration >> Web, I got an 404 error when saving. But I can change all other fields and it saves as expected.
The vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public">
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow, deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what your secure and unsecure urls have trailing slash: http://domain.com/
The same for skin, js, css paths: {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

After that check your .htaccess file, especially RewriteEngine and RewriteBase params. In most cases next values working fine:

```
Options All
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

If you use Apache vhosts, check vhost config. In VirtualHost section you need next lines:

```
<VirtualHost>

 ...

 <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

 RewriteEngine On

 ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes, all the urls have trailing slash. And the .httacces is with those values. I'm running it on an apache vhost, I don't know if that makes difference.

Comment: Can you provide Apache vhost config? Also please check my edited answer above.

Comment: edited the question with the vhost configuration. I still have the error. Thanks

Comment: add <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public"> section, as described in my answer, into your vhost configuration - now you have AllowOverride=None for /var/www directory which contain your site.

Comment: I've made the changes. No success.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changes? Please add your vhost config after changes.

Comment: Yes, I restarted apache after changes. I edited the question with the new configuration, sorry about that, I don't know much about server configuration. Thanks for your time. But I still have the path problem.